# FCGIWrapper 100% CPU Usage

Tags: php, apache, magento, magento2, fastcgi

I have installed Magento v2.3.4 website on VPS with below config:

```
OS: CentOS
CPU: 2 x 2.2 Ghz
RAM: 2 GB
```

Whenever the website is accessed, I see a sudden spike in CPU usage & it goes upto 100%. This causes website to load slow, even for just one user.

`htop` shows multiple of these command being executed:
[image: htop output]

Apache/httpd block generated via DirectAdmin responsible for above is:

```
<Directory /home/admin/public_html>
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
            FCGIWrapper '/usr/local/safe-bin/fcgid73.sh /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/php/mysite.com.ini -d sendmail_from="admin@mysite.com" -d open_basedir="/home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php73/lib/php/" -d mail.log="/home/admin/.php/php-mail.log"' .php
                <FilesMatch "\.php$">
                    SetHandler fcgid-script
                        Options +ExecCGI
                </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
            suPHP_Engine ON
            suPHP_UserGroup admin admin
</Directory>
```

How should I address the issue? Please guide.

Comment: If you create a new PHP file in the document root with only an echo statement in it, do you get the same issue if you access that file? I'm just trying to determine if the issue is caused by the web server or the code in Magento

Comment: @MagnusEriksson same issue with just an echo in a PHP file.

Comment: Then it's probably a server issue (some config or something). Check with the hosting provider or try asking over at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/). SO is more for programming issues than server/system issues.

Comment: Alright. Btw, I did a fresh installation of WordPress and CPU usage is around 10-25% for same command.

Comment: Did that have the same vhost settings as your magento site?

Comment: Exactly same except the document root statement.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reduce the high CPU usage by following below:

1. Clearing the cache by issuing below commands:

   `bin/magento cache:clean`

   `bin/magento cache:flush`
2. Enabling all the cache types from Magento admin panel.

Now the CPU usage hardly goes above 15-20%.

Hope this helps someone! :)